# Difference between two similar queries that cause different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tbl` and I want to extract count of some data from it.

As simplified, I have two choices:

```
select count(if(c10=7,1,null)) as recordCount
from tbl
where cId in (
    select max(cId)
    from tbl
    group by c37
);
```

and

```
select count(*) as recordCount
from (
    select max(cId)
    from tbl
    where c10 = 7
    group by c37
) t1;
```

The first query returns 151 and the second returns 156.

Why do these two queries have different results?

Comment: They're both "true"; the result are correct for the query written. I don't really understand what you mean by "which result is true?"

Comment: Thanks @Larnu for your reply. As I said: `The first code returns 151 and the second returns 156.`, these two codes have different results although it's expected that both codes have same performance.

Comment: So the obvious answer is that they *aren't* the same. The thing that is false is your understanding, not the results from the query. Which is correct for what you want, we don't know. Explain the problem you are trying to solve. Provide sample data and expect results; then we can answer the question you actually want/need to ask.

Comment: OK @Larnu. I'll prepared it. Thanks.

Comment: Asking for clarification isn't a waste of time, @Hogan . It's a great way to get an unclear question improved, as we can work together to get a question that might get closed to be a *good* question.

Comment: @larnu This ***is*** reproducible (I could create the data myself), and ***is not*** caused by typos (it's faulty reasoning / logic, not a typo).

Comment: I didn't say it was a typo, @MatBailie . Personally, I voted the question as unclear.

Comment: @larnu I'm asserting that neither part of the close reason is valid.

Comment: The close reason displayed doesn't reflect my vote, @MatBailie . You'd have to discuss that with the other 2 voters. I agree it's not typographical.

Comment: Because filtering out the values early will change the set of maximum values will be in the output.

Comment: First query; count groups where the ***last row*** (due to `MAX()`) has a 7. Second query; count groups that contain a 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Count(if(c10=7,1,null)) as recordCount
from tbl 
where cId in (select max(cId) 
              from tbl 
              group by c37);
```

In English -- for every grouping of c37 take the one with max id -- from records that match those ids if c10 = 7 then count them

```
Select Count(*) as recordCount
from (Select max(cId) 
      from tbl 
      where c10=7 
      group by c37) t1;
```

In English -- for every grouping of c37 with c10 is 7 take the max id -- count those.

---

I wrote the above to try and figure out what the queries are doing.  Then I saw the issue as described below.

As for your question, it makes no sense the numbers would be different until you consider that max(cID) could be null in the second one but can't be in the first one. -> You can have null in a row in a table, but you can't have it when you use an IN statement.

To show this is the case run the following query

```
SELECT X
FROM (
  Select max(cId) as X
  from tbl 
  where c10=7 
  group by c37
) Z
WHERE X IS NULL
```

I'd expect you to get 4 rows back.

To get the same result for both queries use the following for the 2nd query

```
Select Count(X) as recordCount
from (Select max(cId) X
      from tbl 
      where c10=7 
      group by c37) t1;
```

Comment: The `MAX(cId)` in query two does nothing. It would give the same result if it was `SELECT 1`; *how many c37 groups contain a 7 in cid*.  The first query, I can't adequately put in to words. It can "over count" if `cId` isn't unique (because the subquery isn't / can't be correlate on `c37`), and can under count if `cid` can be NULL. The first query should never be used, its purpose and behaviour are not nearly as clear as the second query (not to mention more costly to execute).

Comment: Yes that is true because COUNT(*) was used in the outer query.  If you count(X) like my example then the max(cID) matters.  @MatBailie

Comment: The Op's first query can still "over count" relative to your suggestion; if `cid` isn't unique. *(I'd also select c37 in your diagnostic query, though I can't up vote again, so there's little motivation to do so.)*

Comment: @MatBailie -- good point.  Clearly there are only 1 item groups for c37 for these results.

Comment: @Hogan, you said `I'd expect you to get 4 rows back.` I ran your query but it returned 'no row' result. I have no null value for my ids. They maybe repeated in table but they can not be null.

Comment: @MortezaM -- interesting did the last query I post fix the problem

Comment: That's the same as my second query. Just you use `X` instead of `*` !

Comment: Related to my program structure, I need to use one of them in somewhere and another in somewhere else. I thought these two queries have same results, but I went wrong!

Comment: @mortezam COUNT(*) counts all rows, COUNT(X) only counts rows where X IS NOT NULL. So, no, it's not the same. And kindly don't shout, especially at people helping you.

Comment: Dear @MatBailie, I don't want to shout anyone! That is misunderstanding. I should improve my English skills ;)

Comment: Dear @Hogan, I tested `Count(X)` and it leads to same result as my second query: 156.

Comment: The first query counts groups where the last row (by cid) has a 7. If then 7 is elsewhere, it won't count.

Comment: Demo and fix; https://dbfiddle.uk/IELjW3BW

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie. That was helpful for my understanding.

Comment: @MortezaM My ***strong*** recommendation is to NOT use the first query, even with my proposed fix. It's a maintenance nightmare, and the second query is also faster and resilient to duplicates and NULLs. It's better in every way.

Comment: @MatBailie. It's 3:30 a.m. here and I went to bed. I'll check your suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: Final comment... fiddle showing it break, why it breaks, how to fix it, and that breaking the assumptions (UNIQUE and NOT NULL) can still break it anyway; https://dbfiddle.uk/jG5IPo80